# OpenTK in OpenGL-less machine?

Tags: c#, .net, opengl, opentk, fallback

I'm interested in [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/) for a **non-game** application whose main concerns are getting complex 2D graphics done fast (hopefully beyond the limits of optimized GDI+).
However, if hardware acceleration is unavaliable in a computer, I still want my application to run, even if with slower graphics output.

Is it possible to use OpenTK, but still have the code work on computers without the graphics card/drivers requirements?
My search yielded [Mesa3D](http://www.mesa3d.org/), but I'm clueless as to how it would integrate in a .NET application, and if such a solution would work for Mono too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenTK makes use of whatever OpenGL version is available on your system.  When you install drivers for a vendor graphics card, you are (also) installing their version of OpenGL.  In the absence of hardware-accelered OpenGL version, most (all?) modern operating systems have a software OpenGL implementation that they fall back onto.  This should work seemlessly without you having to do anything.  However, on Windows, this will probably be quite an ancient OpenGL version (1.1), which will may not support everything you want to do.

Comment: So let's say I'm interested only in simple, commonplace features, such as alpha compositing, fast scaling of images, maybe blending modes and that kind of 2D acceleration. Can I be sure it will still work, even if slower, on an old PC? The way to try it out should be a virtual machine then?

Comment: Chances are, if the machine supports .NET, then you're not going to have any real issues with OpenGL.  That being said, OpenTK's debug version automatically checks the return value of all OpenGL calls, which can be a big help in debugging issues specific to different hardware/driver versions.  If compatibility with a wide variety of hardware is important to you, then it's best to actually get your hands on the hardware you intend to support.